# Bluetooth volume resets to a lower level whenever the iOS Music app advances to the next track

Tags: ios, bluetooth, sound-volume, music.app

While listening to the system Music app on iOS 12.1, I can use the volume buttons on my Bluetooth headphones (BeatsX) to raise or lower the music volume.

However, when the app advances to the next track, the music volume decreases to a lower level. I can raise it again with the headphone volume controls, but it will be reset again when advancing to the next track.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Does it do this in other Apps like Spotify or Amazon Music?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to have been caused by the **Volume Limit** setting of the Music app.

It seems that adjusting the volume via Bluetooth will bypass the volume limit, and allow higher volumes. However, the app will reapply the limit without warning whenever it switches tracks, resulting in the observed volume reset.

The workaround is to turn off the Volume Limit setting.